# Programatically post to twitter from Ruby without registering phone

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am trying to post to a twitter programatically from Ruby, to my own twitter account. I have looked at the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), and it seems ok. However, I need to register an app and register my phone.

I tried to follow this link and do as it says:
https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web

It turns out that I live in a place where none of the carriers are supported, so I simply cannot register my phone.

I found these two links, which both seems to be outdated: http://ruby.about.com/od/networking/qt/twittergem.htm
http://ruby.about.com/od/networking/qt/tweetruby.htm

So how can I post programatically to twitter from ruby when they don't let me register my phone?

Comment: I found a work-around. I used a third party app that lets me do this. In my case I use IFTTT and set up a trigger where I can send an email, and it's tweeted. There are probably other ways to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

File a ticket with Twitter's Platform Operations team if you're unable to associate a mobile number to your account and are therefore blocked from registering a new application at https://apps.twitter.com/

File at ticket at:
https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform